# Extending Jump Point Search to return nearest feasible point to target incase no path is available

Tags: graph-algorithm, path-finding, a-star

I am working on a path finding algorithm for a battle game. The game has concepts of buildings(target) enclosed by walls(obstacles). Soldiers are deployed outside the walls. So in case walls have a gap through which soldiers can pass they will find the path using some path finding algorithm. I have implemented Jump Point Search algo for this purpose, and my algo is working fine. Now I want to extend the algorithm so that in case no path is available it returns me path to the wall/obstacle closest to the target. As a test I kept a bestPoint. Initially bestPoint in my start point(point where soldier is deployed). As Jump Point searches various points any point with less heuristic score that the previous best point is saved in bestPoint as new best point. Eventually if no path is found path is backtraced from last best point. This seems to work for some cases, but in others the soldiers move to odd places on grid. Any better ideas for the said problem?

Comment: Does [this](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/35253) help?  Unfortunately I don't know much about jump-point search, so I don't know how relevant that technique would be.

Comment: Thanks that helped! Although I was trying the same thing but the thread gave me confidence to pursue it further. Since Jump point Search does not need to calculate heuristic score for every point visited, that caused the odd behavior I mentioned.

Comment: Did you find a solution?